# Is there a gradle script to compile eclipse android project?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Does anyone know of gradle script to compile android projects in eclipse project format.  I know you can convert them over to studio, but this can be tons of work and I have many projects runnning off maven. i would like to just use a script to compile my eclipse android projects as they are using gradle. Since gradle is so flexible, I see no reason there should not be a ready made one for eclipse project? But is there?

Comment: open the project in android studio, it does everything itself

Comment: Read the question Prakhar. Then upvote my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes there is, not being a geek I won't keep it to myself:
name this file build.gradle and put in the root of your eclipse project directory:

```
  buildscript {
     repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.4.0'
   }
 }
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


 android {
   lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
   }

   compileSdkVersion 22
   buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

  defaultConfig {
     targetSdkVersion 22
  }

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
    // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-  types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
    // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/...   which would
    // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
    // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
    // by a similar customization.
    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
 }
}
```

And I will give credit to: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBuild/article.html#building_gradle